# XSS in HTML title tag

Tags: xss, html

I got a parameter in URL that displays in the HTML `<title>` tag. The `>` and `<` are properly escaped. Charset cant be changed. No variants (e.g. hex, url, double url, base64) of encoding `<` and `>` are working.

The title tag is somewhat of a special case, since it doesnt have any onEvent attributes. Is there any other way to perform an XSS attack without closing the tag with `</title>`?

Answer (score 3):

I would not treat the `<title>` tag any differently than I would treat any other tag, lika a `<div>`. The context you are talking about (inbetween HTML tags) is what OWASP call "HTML Element Content" in their [XSS prevention cheet sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). They recommend the following substitution rules:

```
& --> &amp;
< --> &lt;
> --> &gt;
" --> &quot;
' --> &#x27;
/ --> &#x2F;
```

However, I can not for the life of me figure out how you would be able to do any mischief without `<` or `>`, so I *think* (as opposed to *know*) that you are safe. Still, there is no harm in following the OWASP recommendations to the letter.

*In other contexts other sanitation rules are required, so do not take this as just endocing `<` and `>` is always OK. It is not.*

Comment: I would've thought an attack would be even less effective if you did the encoding for them. To encode the `<` yourself and pass `&lt;` instead is surely 'safer'? I could be wrong. +1 anyway.

Comment: y, ive read owasp ofc. And if they ask to prevent other symbols like quotes or ampersand there must be a way to use only them to attack. That's what im looking for. Btw, i've tryed URL encoding (single or double) and hex encoding - all useless

Comment: `And if they ask to prevent other symbols like quotes or ampersand there must be a way to use only them to attack`. What do you mean? Supposing you're the attacker, are you asking whether you can bypass the encoding of `<` and `>` by injecting script without other characters instead?

Comment: @Jin Maybe, it seems impossible to me. But that does not mean it is... I am hoping for more answers!

Answer (score 1):

If the question is *"Why do we need to encode characters other than < and >"*, this is because corner cases possibly exist. A naive example would be when the input from a text box is used to generate, say, an href, or an image source on the fly.

**Possiblities:**

```
<img src="&{alert('XSS Vulnerable')};">
```

The special character “&” is sometimes interpreted as a new JavaScript code segment (entity).

```
" [event]='code'
```

In many cases it may be possible for an attacker to insert an exploit string, with the above syntax, into a HTML tag that should have been like:

```
<A HREF="exploit string">Go</A>
```

resulting in:

```
<A HREF="" [event]='code'">Go</A>

<b onMouseOver="self.location.href='http://bad.com/'">text</b>
```

As the client cursor moves over the bolded text, an intrinsic event occurs and the JavaScript code is executed.

There are many more corner/obscure (in today's world) cases where encoding just < or > may not be enough. Look up http://www.technicalinfo.net/papers/CSS.html for a decent (if not slightly outdated) run through of similar cases.

Comment: I agree with what you say here, but the question is about putting  the untrusted data in the title, e.g. `<title>[untrusted data]</title>`. I don't think your examples would work there.